# Can I create a single Redirect Test for my create and edit page in Google Optimize?

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize

We are trying to run a **Redirect Test with Google Optimize** on our booking page. So basically there are **two different page** that we want to test. But **each page, has two different URL**. One for create and another for edit.

For example:

1. Variant A

   - [www.example.com/create/booking/a](http://www.example.com/create/booking/a)
   - [www.example.com/edit/booking/a](http://www.example.com/edit/booking/a)
2. Variant B

   - [www.example.com/create/booking/b](http://www.example.com/create/booking/b)
   - [www.example.com/edit/booking/b](http://www.example.com/edit/booking/b)

So basically we want to create a test that when users visit whether create or edit url they will be redirected to the variant they get respectively.

Let's say **I get Variant A** from the beginning. So when I **visit create page**, I will be **redirected to Variant A create page**. And when I **visit edit page**, I will also be **redirected to Variant A edit page**. This rule also apply if I get Variant B.

Is this possible to implement in a single Google Optimize Redirect Test? Or any other suggestion that can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with custom Javascript in your variation code.

1. Edit variation
2. Choose **Select elements**
3. enter `head` as the selector
4. Click **Add Change** and select **Javascript**
5. Enter the javascript code to redirect accordingly

An example of that script might be (and there are many, many ways you might want to code this):

```
switch(location.pathname){
  case '/create/booking/a':
    location.assign('/create/booking/b'); 
    break;

  case '/create/edit/a':
    location.assign('/create/edit/b');
    break;

  default:
      console.log('Here is a scenario you forgot about, or the URL targeting is too broad');
}
```

[image: example javascript]

[image: Step 1]

Comment: Actually, I already implement it with almost the same approach you describe, but I use GTM instead. As on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04EI8MWvEAY. And I add redirection inside the variant. But there is flickering problem like before redirecting, the browser show actual page first. Your solution might solve this. Thanks!

Comment: This will be difficult to solve 100% perfectly, but you can add the hiding classes to your page: https://developers.google.com/optimize/. This would hide the entire `body` until (a) optimize loads, or (b) page loads completely - whichever is first.